# Solving this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left ( \frac n {n+1} \right)^n$ when applying ratio test on this series..

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

if I want to check the convergence of the series
$$\sum\frac{n!}{n^n}$$
While solving using Ratio test , I encountered this limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac n {n+1} \right)^n$$
is it correct to solve it as following 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac 1 {1+\frac 1 n} \right)^n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1 { \left( 1+\frac 1 n \right)^n}=e^{-1}$$
**(I know that the limit gives here exponential($-1$) but I feel it is wrong to remove the power n from the numerator )**

Note: 
I solved it also by taking ln to the limit and applying l'hopital , I got exponential(-1) also ,but it is very long .. So I want more shorter way and I do not know whether this shorter way correct or not ..

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: It's correct. Removing the power $n$ from the numerator works here, because your numerator is the constant $1$, and $1^n = 1$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Another way to think about this is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n$$

Comment: But here n tends to infinity and 1 to the power infinity is an indeterminate form , not 1 ! ..

Comment: @Sousa If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **absolutely correct** infact it's always true that:

$$\left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^n = \frac{a^n}{b^n} $$